# Database Naming Convention

Tags: php, database-design, naming-conventions

I have been following the following naming convention for my database.

1. lower case letters and plurals for all table names.
2. _ (Underscore) in a table defines a relationship to parent table.
3. _ (Underscore) in a column defines a Foreign Key.

As i prefer using descriptive names for tables and columns i often find myself using camelCasing for an entity that have two or more words and which does not define any relationship. for example.

```
lastVisitIp
lastVisitDate
registrationDate
```

to be frank i don't really like the idea of using camelCasing as i feel it is somewhat ugly to do so and i have no idea why.

i would like to know from the experts what is your take on naming the column in this situation? should i go ahead and use camel casing, should i use an `Underscore(_)` or any other alternative.?

P.S : I checked with the naming convention used in Wordpress and they are using `(_) Underscore` for multi purpose. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find plurals can make things sometime complicated coz plulars can be 's' in case of Users table or 'ies' in case of table name is Companies . So better to stick with singular all the time . Also at the time of sql joining on statement I tend to make mistake with `Users.user_id = Companies.owner_id`  but not with `User.user_id = Company.owner_id`  since you have to be care-full with 's' and 'ies' all the time.

Underscore are prefered way since column name can be made of many words

`is_user_registered_last_year`  Vs `isUserRegisteredLastYear`

as you can see with more alphabets its 
harder to read camel case .

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that this is an old post, but I'd like to add my two cents.

Database tables should if possible, be named as plural, but try to keep some sort of sensibility about them, so that the name is indicative of the contents so that it is easily identifiable.

Take for example the following.

You have users in your application, your model would be `User` as it refers to a single user, the database table would be `users` as it is a collection of the individual users. Now say that you have profiles for these users, there are a few options at naming this, but one that I feel really fits.

1. You may be tempted to name this table `users_profiles`, but when read, this could imply a one to many relationship, being it is the users profiles.
2. You may also be tempted to name this table `user_profile`, which does suggest that it's a one to one relationship, but on the other hand, it does imply that this table isn't a collection, but a single profile for a single user.
3. Instead, the best naming convention for this would be `user_profiles` as it is a collection of user profiles, being that one profile is related to one user.

Within this profile table you'll want to reference the original user, so you'd have a column called `user_id`, not `users_id`, but `user_id`. As for any other column name, you should try to keep it as a single word, all lowercase. In the event that you can't name this column using a single word, treat it like a variable and name it with underscores. This is beneficial as in the instance where you have several columns where the first word is the same, it create a sort of sub collection implying that they are related, which would be correct.

It is true that underscores imply a relationship, which is why the table is called `user_profiles`, and the field is called `user_id`, but 9 times out of 10, you won't have a relationship on a field that isn't an id, so the issue of implication disappears.

There is mention above of always using singular as plural can be confusing. The argument was that plural can end in `s` or `ies`. It's worth noting that `ies` does in fact end in `s`, so the issue is a misnomer. On top of that, keeping the table name as singular, actually creates more confusion as it doesn't immediately imply a collection, and it does mean that the table names can end in pretty much any other letter.

There are tables whose names would imply plural without it ending in an `s`. For example, this could be something like `user_history`. This table name is a perfectly acceptable and easily identifiable name, as history is by default, plural, and this table contains the history for a user.

**Things not to do**

- Mix underscores and cases. Pick one standard and follow it, do not have CamelCase columns combined with underscores as it can be confusing and also look messy.
- Keep everything lowercase. There is no need to use uppercase letters as it can only add to the confusion, treat table and column names like an extract of a spoken or written sentence, but obviously replace the space with an underscore.

As you can see from all the responses here, there are many different options, some with merit, some without. This particular method is one I follow religiously, and to my knowledge, is the most used when it comes to PHP. It keeps things tidy, easily understandable and rarely, if ever, do I see a table name and have no idea what it does.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Be consistent

If you are going to use prefixes, use it everywhere. If you are going to have a foreign key to another table, use the same column name everywhere. If you are going to separate words with underscores, do that everywhere.

How you structure your naming conventions is up to you, just keep it logical so when you come back a months later you know what the table do.

Myself, I use underscore and I do it everywhere, so everything makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking exactly the same think yesterday for a new big project I am about to begin and I got to the same conclusion: use `_` to define relationships and FKs, camel case everything else. An example:

```
party
partyPerson
partyOrganization
partyPerson_partyOrganization (how a person relates to an organization)
partyOrganizationLegal
party_address
party_contactMechanism
address
contactMechanism
```

If you underscore everything it will be harder to spot what is a reference and what isn't.

I also think you should use singular names everywhere (it's more logical and less likely to confuse you).

Comment: i followed plurals because cakePHP recommends using it even though i don't use framework. time for me to change and start using plural instead.

Comment: @Ibrahim: Cake uses plurals because RoR uses plurals, but they both have a different sort of magic working for them. =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which SQL software is being used, but since you mention WordPress, I'm guessing this mostly applies to MySQL.

I would add to what others say and recommend that table names are all lowercase as opposed to camelCase.

While it is possible to use uppercase characters, you might run into hard to track down issues when changing the environment of the database from something UNIX-y to Windows, or more specifically case-sensitive to case-insensitive OSes.

I usually encounter this when pushing or pulling content from a remote DB to a local development machine in Windows.

For more info on this, see the MySQL manual:

> To avoid problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a
>   consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to
>   databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is
>   recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.
>
> -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html